# Attach "Change" event to select2 list created with d3

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, jquery-select2

I'm having trouble successfully listening to a change on a select2 list created with d3.js

```
list = d3.select('.root').append('input').attr('type', 'hidden');

$(list).select2({
    placeholder: "Default",
    data: { results: data, text: 'text' },
    matcher: function(term, text, datum) {
        return text.toUpperCase().indexOf(term.toUpperCase())>=0 || datum.type.indexOf(term.toLowerCase())>=0;
    }
});
```

This successfully creates the select2 list and I'm able to choose values.

However, I'm unable to bind a function to the change event, which I believe I should be able to like this:

```
list.on('change', function(){
    console.log('Selected: ' + $(this).val());
});
```

Am I able to do this or do I need to explicitly use a selector for the input  element?

```
$('.root > input').on('change', function(){
    console.log('Selected: ' + $(this).val());
});
```

See a (non) working fiddle here :)

http://jsfiddle.net/LbLjc/1/

Comment: I guess you are missing one curly closing brace in '$(list).select2(....' call.

Comment: A detail here: I believe the answers below are addressing the fact that the element is hidden, not that it was created dynamically. Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cRV7G/1/) that I have created for another question where I have html and svg elements created dynamically and listeners applied to them without the need for delegation. Is my observation accurate?

Comment: Your fiddle is not using a select2, which I believe is the root of why I'm having this issue (see updated link with fiddle)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way to do this is to iterate over the items in the d3 object and attach the handler to all of them:

```
list.forEach(function(elem) {
  $(elem).on('change', log)
});
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LbLjc/3/

If you are confident you only want the first one, you can shorten it to:

```
$(list[0]).on('change', log);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use **[event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)** here since your `input` elements have been added dynamically to the DOM:

```
$('body').on('change', '.root > input', function(){
    console.log('Selected: ' + $(this).val());
});
```

Comment: So in this case, I don't want to use a blanket selector in case I add more select2 lists dynamically. I want to bind to the change event of this particular list, whose DOM node I thought was referenced in the d3 object.

Answer (score 0):

Since your ellements are created dynamically, you should use [***event delegation***](https://api.jquery.com/on/) for that

```
$('.root').on('change',"input", function(){
 console.log('Selected: ' + $(this).val());
});
```